# AS400: Dealing with Multiple schema's while connecting to AS400 System

Tags: jdbc, ibm-midrange

I am using the below driver to connect to AS400 system.

“jdbc:as400://system-name/default-schema;properties”

I have a requirement where in i have to deal with multiple schema's.

As the schema name need to be mentioned in the JDBC URL, do i need to open separate connection pool for each schema i am trying to connect?

Currently there are two connection pool i am using for two different schema pointing to same DB properties.

Is there any other way to deal with multiple schema with single connection.

Comment: BTW, that string is not your driver.  It is more of a template for your connection string.

Answer (score 3):

A schema is more commonly referred to as a library on the IBM i (AS/400).

You can use a single database connection and qualify the table names with `schema.table` for the default SQL naming convention or `schema/table` with the system naming convention.

See the "naming" property in the [IBM Toolbox for Java JDBC properties](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Frzahh%2Fjdbcproperties.htm) section of the [Toolbox](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/rzahh/page1.htm) programmer's guide and [SQL and system naming conventions](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/sqlp/rbafyterms.htm) topic in the [SQL Programming](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/sqlp/rbafykickoff.htm) guide for more information.

Comment: A somewhat recent update to IBM i 7.1 enables using the `schema.table` notation under system naming as well as the OS/400 style `schema/table`.  But not everyone using 7.1 is necessarily current on the latest Technology Refresh.

Comment: Fixed the link for Toolbox JDBC properties

Answer (score 1):

By using "system naming" settings your session can take advantage of a "library list" attribute which each job has. It is a list of schemes that is searched when the system is resolving the location of an unqualified object. The concept is similar to the notion of a path in Windows or Linux.

In addition to the links that @JamesA provided, also read the two part [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibmi/library/i-sqlnaming/) by Birgitta Hauser, and the SQL Reference on [unqualified names](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fdb2%2Frbafzqualun.htm).

It is commonly considered best practice to use the session (ie job) library list, rather than statically  hardcoding schema names. I suggest you follow this practice. While the terms schema and library are essentially synonymous, I use the IBM i command CHGCURLIB, rather than SET CURRENT SCHEMA, because the command does not restrict the behavior of SQL regarding the library list. But my understanding from Birgitta's article, is that SET CURRENT SCHEMA blocks the use of the library list entirely.  The current library becomes the first library on (the user portion of) your library list.